# Google Maps API div in another div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, html

Today I started to implement Google maps into my site, but I've ran into a problem, because the div with the maps provided for me can't be put into another div?!

I use the code stated on [this site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=de) and when I do something like

```
<div><div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div></div>
```

it stops working. Why? I don't want my maps to be displayed over the whole page, I want it to be displayed in an normal div which I can restyle whenever I want...

Comment: added an update to my answer which 'may' help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the `div` `map_canvas`. It doesn't need putting inside another `div` to do that.

So for example, change your code to this:

```
     <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

And CSS:

```
#map_canvas{
    width:400px; /* your own height here */
    height:300px;  /* your own height here */
     border:solid 1px green;  /* your own border if you like */

    /* maybe you want to position it somewhere? you can do for example */
   position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px; 

 }
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently you need to set the width & height on the parent DIVS too. I haven't tested this yet, though try the following:

```
<div id="mapHolder"><div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div></div>


#mapHolder {width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Failing that, have you tried an absolute size, rather than % as in my CSS at the top of this answer?

Comment: thanks for your answer. i've came up with the same solution (height is required) at the same time :) but i wil give you the green check!

Answer (score 0):

Change style sheet like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #map_canvas { width : 500px; height : 500px; }
</style>
```

And also get rid the inline stylesheet from the div tag.

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but that was not really my question. I'm using bootstrap and so it is unavoidable that there is a div inside a div (like row divs), and that is not working with google maps?!

Comment: No, I don't think so. Could you show us your whole code? That helps for us.

Comment: wrong alert guys, i came up with the solution to add a height to the parent div!! but thank you very much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

you can re-size the map by change the width and height values. so

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:50%; height:50%"></div>
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but that was not really my question. I'm using bootstrap and so it is unavoidable that there is a div inside a div (like row divs), and that is not working with google maps?!

Comment: thanks for your help. the solution is to give the parent div a specific height!

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have

```
<div><div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div></div>
```

This should not work because your parent div has no `width` and `height`. When you are using `width/height` in `%`, the element measures the dimension depending on it's parent element. If you apply some width and height to your parent `element/div`, i.e.

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px"><div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div></div>
```

then the inner div (map_canvas) will apply the width and height to itself `100%` of `300px`. Alternatively you can remove the outer div. Hope it helps.